# Why does my Java RSA encryption give me an Arithmetic Exception?

Tags: java, .net, encryption, rsa

In .NET I have generated the following public key file:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
   <Modulus>xTSiS4+I/x9awUXcF66Ffw7tracsQfGCn6g6k/hGkLquHYMFTCYk4mOB5NwLwqczwvl8HkQfDShGcvrm47XHKUzA8iadWdA5n4toBECzRxiCWCHm1KEg59LUD3fxTG5ogGiNxDj9wSguCIzFdUxBYq5ot2J4iLgGu0qShml5vwk=</Modulus>
   <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

.NET is happy to encrypt using it's normal methods.

I am trying to use this key to encode a string in Java. I am running into an Arithmetic Exception when I attempt to encrypt the string.

The following is the code I am using to encrypt:

```
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode(this.getString(R.string.public_key_modulus));
byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(this.getString(R.string.public_key_exponent));
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger( modulusBytes );                
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger( exponentBytes);

RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal( new String("big kitty dancing").getBytes() );
```

It is the final line in the code block that fails.

I have looked at numerous examples and this is the best I could come up with.  If it is not obvious, the R.string.public_key_modulus is a copy/paste of the text in the Modulus element, same applies for exponent.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes );
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);
```

Otherwise you end up with a negative modulus. The `BigInteger(byte[])` constructor assumes a *signed* big-endian representation. The `BigInteger(int, byte[])` constructor uses the provided sign bit (here "1" for "positive").

Also, be wary of `String.getBytes()`, it uses the platform "default charset" which depends on the configuration of the machine on which the application runs. It is better to specify an explicit charset (e.g. `"UTF-8"`) if you want reproducible results.